# How to show the loading dialog

Tags: android

I try use below code to load an URL.

```
URL url = new URL(urlstr);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();  //spend lots of time
```

Because the line `InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();` will spend some time.
So I want to show a loading dialog while it loading.
I can I do it?

In AActivity, below code to call BActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = MyGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BActivity", intent);  
View view = w.getDecorView();  
MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

And BActivity is load URL and extract information.
The load code is in onCreate().

I try the answer code, the error `Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@2afe9488 is not valid; is your activity running?` shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve with the aysntask showing progress dialog as follows

In Oncreate :

```
         new GetTask(this).execute();//taken object for asyntask class.



    class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
     {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
       void GetTask(Context cntxt)
      {

      }
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(cntxt); //taking object for progress dialog
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.show(); //Displaying progressDialog
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

         //do the background process

        return ""; you can return string value

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();//close the progress Dialog
        }

     }
      }
```

Comment: i think we should use 
 if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();//close the progress Dialog
        }

instead of

if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();//close the progress Dialog
        }

Answer (score 1):

You want a ProgressDialog. Refer to this [link](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/showing-progressdialog-in-android-activity/)

Answer (score 1):

Progress dialog

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
    public  void showProgress () {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Use asynchronous task for downloding...

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                //Do your downloading task

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                 dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        }
```

Call progress dialog before executing download task

```
showProgress();
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.url.com" });
```

Comment: Please replace `this` with `YourActivityName.this`

Answer (score 1):

use a constructor in DownloadWebPageTask to initialize the context and use that context in dialog.

or use yourclass.this in
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourclass.this);